# Binding to an attached property in code behind

Tags: wpf, binding, properties

How can I implement the following xaml binding in code behind?

```
<Canvas x:Name="_YAxis">
    <Label Content="0.2" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Bottom="{Binding ElementName=_YAxis, Path=ActualHeight, Converter={StaticResource myPercentageOf}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource Constant_pt2} }"  />
</Canvas>
```

Note, the converter simply multiplies the actual height of the Canvas by 0.2

I can sort out most kind of bindings, but this one has me stumped.

I can create the binding using

```
Label label = new Label() { label.Content = "0.2" };

Binding binding = new Binding("ActualHeight");
binding.Source = _YAxis;

// attach binding ???

_YAxis.Children.Add(label);
```

but how do I attach the binding to the Canvas.Left attached property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
    Binding b = new Binding();
    b.Path = new PropertyPath("ActualHeight");
    b.Source = _YAxis;// OR b.ElementName = "_YAxis"
    b.Converter = Resources["myPercentageOf"];
    b.ConverterParameter = Resources["Constant_pt2"];

    Label label = new Label() { label.Content = "0.2" };
    _YAxis.Children.Add(label);
    label.SetBinding(Canvas.BottomProperty, b); //Binding Canvas.Bottom to ActualHeight of _YAxis
    Canvas.SetLeft(label, 25); //Setting Canvas.Left
```

Comment: I apologise for my rudeness in not thanking you for your response.
I didn't know how to get update notifications so didn't see your response.